# Maximum optimization of element wise multiplication via ARM NEON assembly

Tags: c++, optimization, assembly, arm, neon

I'm optimizing an element wise multiplication of two single dimensional arrays for a dual Cortex-A9 processor. Linux is running on the board and I'm using the GCC 4.5.2 compiler.

So the following is my C++ inline assembler function. src1, src2 and dst are 16 byte aligned.

Update: Testable Code:

```
void Multiply(
    const float* __restrict__ src1,
    const float* __restrict__ src2,
    float* __restrict__ dst,
    const unsigned int width,
    const unsigned int height)
{
    int loopBound = (width * height) / 4;
    asm volatile(
        ".loop:                             \n\t"
        "vld1.32  {q1}, [%[src1]:128]!      \n\t"
        "vld1.32  {q2}, [%[src2]:128]!      \n\t"
        "vmul.f32 q0, q1, q2                \n\t"
        "vst1.32  {q0}, [%[dst]:128]!       \n\t"
        "subs     %[lBound], %[lBound], $1  \n\t"
        "bge      .loop                     \n\t"
        :
        :[dst] "r" (dst), [src1] "r" (src1), [src2] "r" (src2),
        [lBound] "r" (loopBound)
        :"memory", "d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5
    );
}

//The following function describes how to test the element wise multiplication
void Test()
{
    const unsigned int width = 1024, height = 1024;
    float* src1 __attribute__((aligned(16))) = new float[width * height];
    float* src2 __attribute__((aligned(16))) = new float[width * height];
    float* dst __attribute__((aligned(16))) = new float[width * height];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < (width * height); i++)
    {
        src1[i] = (float)rand();
        src2[i] = (float)rand();
    }
    Multiply(src1, src2, dst, width, height);

    std::cout << dst[0] << std::endl;
}
```

The calculation of 1024*1024 values takes ~0.016 s. (Two threads - each thread calculates a half of the array). Naively interpreted, the calculation of one iteration takes 122 cycles. This seems to be a bit slow. But where is the bottleneck?

I even tried the `pld` command for preloading elements in the L2 cache, "unrolling" the loop by calculating up to 20 values per iteration and reordering the instructions to make shure the processor is not waiting for memory. I didn't get that much speedup (max 0.001 s faster).

Do you have any suggestions for speeding up the calculation?

Comment: Have you profiled the code with a single thread only?

Comment: Can you also provide a test harness like code so people can run this locally?

Comment: Have you checked the lower bits of the pointers to verify that the attribute(aligned(16)) produces the expected code?

Comment: I've also profiled it with a single thread. The calculation takes ~ 2x time.
The adress of the pointer is something like 0x????0008.

Comment: new float[width * height];  -here an operator 'new' does not provide an aligned memory. try to use static arrays for tests, or allocate memory dynamically but you must align result pointer manualy

Comment: Thanks for your responses!
Smalti: So should it be enaugh to add the static keyword on the allocation of the three arrays?
The allocation via new is a dynamic memory allocation, right? Or should I rather allocate it with malloc()? But how can I align the pointer manualy?

Comment: I think assembly part is ok, if you call this frequently in a closed module try to get rid of method call overhead by declaring it as static & inline.

Comment: You should also benchmark the memory by just moving data around using vector instructions to see what peek values you can get.

Comment: Yes - via 'new' is dynamic allocation, which consist of 'malloc' and C++ constructor calls, but you can use 'memalign' function for dynamic aligned allocation, f.e.:
size_t alignment = 16;
void* ptr = memalign( alignment, mem_size ); - it is must be enough.

After that, you can use :128 alignment suffix in command.
But it is not fix your problem, because usually it is increase the performance only on about ~5%(in my tests).

Comment: How did you benchmark your code? Did you benchmark *only* the `Multiply()` function, or might have the benchmark included the random number generation? Did you run `Multiply()` multiple times, or just once? How did you measuer the time?

Comment: int a=(int)pointer; pointer=(int*)((a+15)&~15);

Comment: Ok with memalign the 128 bit aligned load / store works now :). Tanks a lot.

Comment: Since the speed of 2 threads is 2x it just rules out that multithreading is (somehow) corrupting cache.

Comment: I measure the calculation time of `Multiply()` via posix timers. `Multiply()` will be called twice in an image processing "pipeline".

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen
the calculation time with one thread behaves like expected. It takes ~0.030s.

Comment: what is your memory bandwidth?

Comment: I'm still thinking it could relate to a cache line conflict -- could you test with allocating say 1300x1024 floats per array?

Comment: Ok finally I've speed up the code to ~0.0145 s for 1024*1024 float values.
Firstly I included two pld instructions. Secondly I replaced the two loads and one store of 1 quadword register to two loads and one store of 2 quadword registers.

AkiSuihkonen: I have to correct my answer with the one thread. The calculation time takes 0.021 s with only one thread. But I think this is caused by the bad load balancing of the threads. (I don't want to optimize it, because mainly I want to check the capabilities of the NEON extension)

@auselen: The maximum memory bandwidth I got were about 400 MByte/s.

Comment: You can probably squeeze a few cycles by moving SUBS to in between load and multiplication.

Comment: My comment about modifying the array sizes deals with the possibility of src1,src2 and dst all using the same cache lines (assuming 2-way set associative cache). They are most probable as exactly 4MB apart from each other as is humanly possible. (+- 16 bytes). As pointed SUBS can be even the first instruction in the loop.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I have modified the array size to 1300*1024. The computation took 0.019 s. I have also optimized 3x3 median-filtering. The strange thing is, that the calculation time (of a 1024*1024 image) only takes about 0.0145 s! It has more load/store operations and also arithmetic operations.

Comment: With these figures, it doesn't seem that bad anymore. You are having anyway a memory bandwidth of 275MBps, which is enough for realtime HD video and which leaves you 120+ instructions to do every kind of magic per pixel...

Comment: Assuming this is really just multiplying 2 vectors elementwise, did you compare with automatic vectorization by the compiler? (you may want to use __builtin_assume_aligned in a more recent version of gcc to help it) You can also use the intrinsics, or the vector extensions. Basically anything that lets the compiler do part of the job.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know that much about the NEON.  However, I think that you have data dependencies that cause performance issues.  I would suggest you prime the loop with some loads and then place them between the *multiply* and *store*.  I think the *store* is probably blocking until the *multiply* is done.

```
    asm volatile(
    "vld1.32  {q1}, [%[src1]:128]!      \n\t"
    "vld1.32  {q2}, [%[src2]:128]!      \n\t"
    ".loop:                             \n\t"
    "vmul.f32 q0, q1, q2                \n\t"
    "vld1.32  {q1}, [%[src1]:128]!      \n\t"
    "vld1.32  {q2}, [%[src2]:128]!      \n\t"
    "vst1.32  {q0}, [%[dst]:128]!       \n\t"
    "subs     %[lBound], %[lBound], $1  \n\t"
    "bge      .loop                     \n\t"
    :
    :[dst] "r" (dst), [src1] "r" (src1), [src2] "r" (src2),
    [lBound] "r" (loopBound)
    :"memory", "d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5
);
```

This way you should be able to *parallel* the loads with the multiply.  You will need to over-allocate the source arrays or change the loop index and do a final  multiply and store.  If the NEON ops are not affecting the condition codes, you can re-order the *subs* as well and place it earlier.

**Edit:** In fact, the *Cortex A-9 Media processing Engine* document recommends interleaving ARM and NEON instructions as they can execute in parallel.  Also, the NEON instructions seem to set *FPSCR* and not the ARM *CPSR* so re-ordering the `subs` would decrease the execution time.  You may also *cache* align the loop.